# Android white screen when running ionic capacitor run with SSL

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm trying to run a simple test, trying to add ionic and capacitor to an already existing angular project. I have managed to make it work and run correctly but when I add the SSL command to the CLI so that the server runs with HTTPS the app no longer loads and everything I can just see is a blank screen. Moreover if I access the URL manually from the browser everything loads correctly. Could it be there's something wrongly configured in Android Studio or the ionic/capacitor files? I have tried different configurations and different emulated devices w/ different Android versions but there's no use, I haven't been able to make it work. I would certainly appreciate if someone could help me with this...

Running `ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljfUT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LxNV.png

When I add the  --ssl flag to the CLI `ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external --ssl`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS0jV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3sLL.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v5Bx.png

## **Capacitor.config**

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'io.ionic.starter',
  appName: 'iotest',
  webDir: './android/www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false
};

export default config;
```

## **Angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
  }, 
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
  "projects": {
    "iotest": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "./android/www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "./node_modules/ionicicons/dist/ionicicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "iotest:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "iotest:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "iotest:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "iotest"
}
```

## **Ionic.config**

```
{
  "defaultProject": "iotest",
  "projects": {
    "iotest": {
      "name": "iotest",
      "integrations": {
        "capacitor": {}
      },
      "type": "angular"
    }
  }
}
```

## Angular

Angular CLI: 12.1.4

Node: 16.14.0 (Unsupported)

Package Manager: npm 8.3.1

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.1.5

... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms

... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version

---------------------------------------------------------

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1201.4

@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.1.4

@angular-devkit/core            12.1.4

@angular-devkit/schematics      12.1.4

@angular/cli                    12.1.4

@schematics/angular             12.1.4

rxjs                            6.6.7

typescript                      4.3.5

Warning: The current version of Node (16.14.0) is not supported by Angular.

## NPM

Version 8.3.1

My goal is to make it run with SSL since in a future I will need to apply this to an app that needs to be run with HTTPS

Comment: please check this link, possibly help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647572/loading-webview-with-https-with-ionic-and-capacitor

Comment: maybe cert issue? have you run `ionic ssl generate` ?

Comment: @MayankJoshi I have tried everything on that post, which I had already seen before but nothing seems to make it work :(

Comment: @slashsharp Apparently it is certainly a cert issue but ssl generate is not the solution for it. Running with the --ssl flag autogenerates certs so that's not really a problem. Besides I have self-signed and trusted certificates already and it doesn't work either way :( Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

From capacitor.config.ts make change like this:

```
{
  ... 
  server: {
    url: 'https://your-local-ip:8100' // like: 192.168.1.66:8100
    androidScheme: 'https',
    clearText: true // just for test
  } 
 ... 
}
```

then open two terminal and run
this command's:

```
ionic cap run android -l --external --ssl
```

from second terminal run:

```
ionic serve 0.0.0.0 --ssl
```

after all if you still see blank page, open a browser from mobile device and go to https://your-host-ip:8100, then make sure the url is trusted.